# How to get all options of jquery datepicker to instanciate new datepicker with same options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How to get all options of jquery datepicker to instanciate new datepicker with same options?

I want clone a table which contains 2 datepickers with different options. You can see here an example : http://jsfiddle.net/qwZ5x/4/

```html
<div class="clonable">
<table><tr><td>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif"
        });
    });
</script></td><td>
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" />
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    });
</script>
    </td></tr></table>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clone">Clone</a>
```

```js
var id = 0;
jQuery("#clone").on("click", function () {

var clonable = jQuery(".clonable:first").clone(true, true);
jQuery(clonable).find("input").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("id", jQuery(this).attr("id") + "_" + id);

    jQuery(this).siblings('.ui-datepicker-trigger,.ui-datepicker-apply').remove();

    jQuery(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker');
    jQuery(this).datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif"
    });
});

jQuery(clonable).insertBefore("#clone");
id = id + 1;
});
```

How can i set all options to cloned datepicker without set option one by one?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

You can get the options of the existing datepicker using this:

```
var options = jquery('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'all');
```

to get one specific option, for example the numberOfMonths:

```
var numberOfMonths = jquery('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'numberOfMonths');
```

Comment: I take it this is deprecated, as it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @DerekHenderson: Not sure....I haven't used jQuery since like 5 years ago.

Comment: I hear you. I am being forced to use it on a project now, not having used it in about 4 years, and thinking "Why exactly does anyone still use this?"

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, replace this:

```
jQuery(this).datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif"
});
```

...with this:

```
jQuery(this).datepicker(jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'all'));
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the change: http://jsfiddle.net/puAde/

This works because you've cloned the input elements, which hold the options, but they need to be re-applied to the new instance.

Note that you need to pass `'all'` to get the current options (the jQuery documentation is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get all the options like this:

```
$('#datepicker').data('datepicker');
$('#daterangepicker').data('daterangepicker');
```

Outputs a specific value:

```
$('#datepicker').data('datepicker').timePickerIncrement
$('#daterangepicker').data('daterangepicker').timePickerIncrement
```